# No beans of type javax.sql.DataSource found. Skipping auto-reconfiguration

Tags: mysql, spring, cloud-foundry, jhipster

I am trying to deploy the default JHipster UUA application to my cloudfoundry (prod profile) with MySQL as the DB option. The MySQL service is created and correctly bound to the app. I have posted the stackstrace and cf env below. Note that I have obscured the connection information with [stuff between brackets].

Two main errors stand out, I suspect the first one being related to the other:

1. No beans of type javax.sql.DataSource found. Skipping
   auto-reconfiguration.
2. 'java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "[generated]@10.10.32.14:3306"'

I am deploying using `yo jhipster:cloudfoundry`, selecting prod profile (but also tried manual) and have edited `bootstrap-prod.yml` and `application-prod.yml` to contain the url to my [Jhipster-registry](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-registry) instance which also runs in the same cloudfoundry space (and had no issues). So `spring.cloud.config.uri` and `client.serviceUrl.defaultZone` become: `http://admin:admin@jhipsterregistry.[my.domain.com]/config`. Furthermore I use the sping connectorers for cloudfoundry and have a datasource defined for my cloud profile used when deploying in production. See below.

```
@Configuration
@Profile(Constants.SPRING_PROFILE_CLOUD)
public class CloudDatabaseConfiguration extends AbstractCloudConfig {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CloudDatabaseConfiguration.class);

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(CacheManager cacheManager) {
        log.info("Configuring JDBC datasource from a cloud provider");
        return connectionFactory().dataSource();
    }
}
```

Pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-spring-service-connector</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-localconfig-connector</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

and my main app.java.

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { MetricFilterAutoConfiguration.class, MetricRepositoryAutoConfiguration.class })
@EnableConfigurationProperties({ JHipsterProperties.class, LiquibaseProperties.class })
@EnableEurekaClient
public class JanusApp { .. }
```

Below are the environment variables and the logs of the failing application. No additional information is provided on the [JHipster](https://jhipster.github.io/microservices-architecture/) website. Any help would be appreciated.

App environment variables:

```
$ cf env janus
Getting env variables for app janus in org [something] / space dev as [someone@something.com]...
OK

System-Provided:
{
 "VCAP_SERVICES": {
  "p-mysql": [
   {
    "credentials": {
     "hostname": "10.10.32.14",
     "jdbcUrl": "jdbc:mysql://[generated]:[generated]@10.10.32.14:3306/cf_42fa757f_80f1_[remainder]",
     "name": "cf_42fa757f_80f1_[remainder]",
     "password": "[generated]",
     "port": 3306,
     "uri": "mysql://[generated]:[generated]@10.10.32.14:3306/cf_42fa757f_80f1_[remainder]?reconnect=true",
     "username": "[generated]"
    },
    "label": "p-mysql",
    "name": "janus",
    "plan": "100mb-dev",
    "provider": null,
    "syslog_drain_url": null,
    "tags": [
     "mysql"
    ]
   }
  ]
 }
}

{
 "VCAP_APPLICATION": {
  "application_id": "435b6c8c-ca4b-46b8-a769-65fc5eacd7dd",
  "application_name": "janus",
  "application_uris": [
   "janus.[my.domain.com]"
  ],
  "application_version": "4c8084ec-3f83-4518-8129-4bf3c3e38594",
  "limits": {
   "disk": 1024,
   "fds": 16384,
   "mem": 1024
  },
  "name": "janus",
  "space_id": "eba312c0-9643-45b7-ba36-d6dfd523e4ae",
  "space_name": "dev",
  "uris": [
   "janus.[my.domain.com]"
  ],
  "users": null,
  "version": "4c8084ec-3f83-4518-8129-4bf3c3e38594"
 }
}
```

Application log:

```
2016-08-12T07:49:32.56+0200 [DEA/56]     OUT Stopping app instance (index 0) with guid 435b6c8c-ca4b-46b8-a769-65fc5eacd7dd
2016-08-12T07:49:32.56+0200 [DEA/56]     OUT Stopped app instance (index 0) with guid 435b6c8c-ca4b-46b8-a769-65fc5eacd7dd
2016-08-12T07:56:06.08+0200 [DEA/12]     OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid 435b6c8c-ca4b-46b8-a769-65fc5eacd7dd
2016-08-12T07:56:11.15+0200 [App/0]      OUT     05:56:11.147 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlPropertiesFactoryBean - Loading from YAML: class path resource [config/application.yml]
2016-08-12T07:56:11.19+0200 [App/0]      OUT 05:56:11.198 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlPropertiesFactoryBean - Merging document (no matchers set): {eureka={instance={appname=janus, instanceId=janus:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}}}, ribbon={eureka={enabled=true}}, management={context-path=/management, health={mail={enabled=false}}}, spring={application={name=janus}, profiles={active=prod}, jackson={serialization.write_dates_as_timestamps=false}, jpa={open-in-view=false, hibernate={ddl-auto=none, naming-strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringNamingStrategy}}, messages={basename=i18n/messages}, mvc={favicon={enabled=false}}, thymeleaf={mode=XHTML}}, security={basic={enabled=false}}, jhipster={async={corePoolSize=2, maxPoolSize=50, queueCapacity=10000}, mail={from=janus@localhost}, swagger={title=janus API, description=janus API documentation, version=0.0.1, termsOfServiceUrl=null, contactName=null, contactUrl=null, contactEmail=null, license=null, licenseUrl=null}, ribbon={displayOnActiveProfiles=dev}}}
2016-08-12T07:56:11.19+0200 [App/0]      OUT 05:56:11.199 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlPropertiesFactoryBean - Loaded 1 document from YAML resource: class path resource [config/application.yml]
2016-08-12T07:56:13.14+0200 [App/0]      OUT 2016-08-12 05:56:13.145  INFO 29 --- [           main] pertySourceApplicationContextInitializer : Adding 'cloud' PropertySource to ApplicationContext
2016-08-12T07:56:13.26+0200 [App/0]      OUT 2016-08-12 05:56:13.266  INFO 29 --- [           main] nfigurationApplicationContextInitializer : Adding cloud service auto-reconfiguration to ApplicationContext
2016-08-12T07:56:14.11+0200 [App/0]      OUT 2016-08-12 05:56:14.116  INFO 29 --- [           main] urceCloudServiceBeanFactoryPostProcessor : Auto-reconfiguring beans of type javax.sql.DataSource
2016-08-12T07:56:14.12+0200 [App/0]      OUT 2016-08-12 05:56:14.119  INFO 29 --- [           main] urceCloudServiceBeanFactoryPostProcessor : No beans of type javax.sql.DataSource found. Skipping auto-reconfiguration.
2016-08-12T07:56:15.25+0200 [App/0]      OUT         ██  ██    ██  ████████  ███████    ██████  ████████  ████████  ███████
2016-08-12T07:56:15.25+0200 [App/0]      OUT         ██  ██    ██     ██     ██    ██  ██          ██     ██        ██    ██
2016-08-12T07:56:15.25+0200 [App/0]      OUT         ██  ████████     ██     ███████    █████      ██     ██████    ███████
2016-08-12T07:56:15.25+0200 [App/0]      OUT   ██    ██  ██    ██     ██     ██             ██     ██     ██        ██   ██
2016-08-12T07:56:15.25+0200 [App/0]      OUT    ██████   ██    ██  ████████  ██        ██████      ██     ████████  ██    ██
2016-08-12T07:56:15.25+0200 [App/0]      OUT :: JHipster   :: Running Spring Boot 1.3.6.RELEASE ::
2016-08-12T07:56:15.25+0200 [App/0]      OUT :: http://jhipster.github.io ::
2016-08-12T07:56:15.86+0200 [App/0]      OUT 2016-08-12 05:56:15.861  INFO 29 --- [           main] nfigurationApplicationContextInitializer : Adding cloud service auto-reconfiguration to ApplicationContext
2016-08-12T07:56:15.86+0200 [App/0]      OUT 2016-08-12 05:56:15.863  INFO 29 --- [           main] com.philips.janus.JanusApp               : The following profiles are active:  cloudfoundry,prod,cloudfoundry,cloud
2016-08-12T07:56:19.13+0200 [App/0]      OUT 2016-08-12 05:56:19.135  WARN 29 --- [           main] o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor  : Cannot enhance @Configuration bean definition 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfiguration$TokenKeyEndpointRegistrar' since its singleton instance has been created too early. The typical cause is a non-static @Bean method with a BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor return type: Consider declaring such methods as 'static'.
2016-08-12T07:56:19.13+0200 [App/0]      OUT 2016-08-12 05:56:19.135  WARN 29 --- [           main] o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor  : Cannot enhance @Configuration bean definition 'refreshScope' since its singleton instance has been created too early. The typical cause is a non-static @Bean method with a BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor return type: Consider declaring such methods as 'static'.
2016-08-12T07:56:19.48+0200 [App/0]      OUT 2016-08-12 05:56:19.481  INFO 29 --- [           main] urceCloudServiceBeanFactoryPostProcessor : Skipping auto-reconfiguring beans of type javax.sql.DataSource
2016-08-12T07:56:19.48+0200 [App/0]      OUT 2016-08-12 05:56:19.482  INFO 29 --- [           main] ongoCloudServiceBeanFactoryPostProcessor : Skipping auto-reconfiguring beans of type org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoDbFactory
2016-08-12T07:56:19.48+0200 [App/0]      OUT 2016-08-12 05:56:19.482  INFO 29 --- [           main] bbitCloudServiceBeanFactoryPostProcessor : Skipping auto-reconfiguring beans of type org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory
2016-08-12T07:56:19.48+0200 [App/0]      OUT 2016-08-12 05:56:19.482  INFO 29 --- [           main] edisCloudServiceBeanFactoryPostProcessor : Skipping auto-reconfiguring beans of type org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory
2016-08-12T07:56:20.85+0200 [App/0]      OUT 2016-08-12 05:56:20.853  INFO 29 --- [           main] c.h.instance.DefaultAddressPicker        : [LOCAL] [dev] [3.6.1] Prefer IPv4 stack is true.
2016-08-12T07:56:20.86+0200 [App/0]      OUT 2016-08-12 05:56:20.867  INFO 29 --- [           main] c.h.instance.DefaultAddressPicker        : [LOCAL] [dev] [3.6.1] Picked Address[10.254.1.126]:5701, using socket ServerSocket[addr=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,localport=5701], bind any local is true
2016-08-12T07:56:21.62+0200 [App/0]      OUT 2016-08-12 05:56:21.627  INFO 29 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.spi.OperationService       : [10.254.1.126]:5701 [dev] [3.6.1] Backpressure is disabled
2016-08-12T07:56:22.59+0200 [App/0]      OUT 2016-08-12 05:56:22.594  INFO 29 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.system                     : [10.254.1.126]:5701 [dev] [3.6.1] Hazelcast 3.6.1 (20160228 - d0d2a77) starting at Address[10.254.1.126]:5701
2016-08-12T07:56:22.59+0200 [App/0]      OUT 2016-08-12 05:56:22.594  INFO 29 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.system                     : [10.254.1.126]:5701 [dev] [3.6.1] Copyright (c) 2008-2016, Hazelcast, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
2016-08-12T07:56:22.59+0200 [App/0]      OUT 2016-08-12 05:56:22.594  INFO 29 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.system                     : [10.254.1.126]:5701 [dev] [3.6.1] Configured Hazelcast Serialization version : 1
2016-08-12T07:56:22.60+0200 [App/0]      OUT 2016-08-12 05:56:22.607  INFO 29 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.instance.Node              : [10.254.1.126]:5701 [dev] [3.6.1] Creating MulticastJoiner
2016-08-12T07:56:22.61+0200 [App/0]      OUT 2016-08-12 05:56:22.614  INFO 29 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService      : [10.254.1.126]:5701 [dev] [3.6.1] Address[10.254.1.126]:5701 is STARTING
2016-08-12T07:56:25.78+0200 [App/0]      OUT 2016-08-12 05:56:25.780  INFO 29 --- [           main] c.h.cluster.impl.MulticastJoiner         : [10.254.1.126]:5701 [dev] [3.6.1]
2016-08-12T07:56:25.78+0200 [App/0]      OUT Members [1] {
2016-08-12T07:56:25.78+0200 [App/0]      OUT    Member [10.254.1.126]:5701 this
2016-08-12T07:56:25.78+0200 [App/0]      OUT }
2016-08-12T07:56:25.84+0200 [App/0]      OUT 2016-08-12 05:56:25.847  INFO 29 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService      : [10.254.1.126]:5701 [dev] [3.6.1] Address[10.254.1.126]:5701 is STARTED
2016-08-12T07:56:28.16+0200 [App/0]      OUT 2016-08-12 05:56:28.165  INFO 29 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.philips.janus.config.WebConfigurer   : Web application configuration, using profiles: [ cloudfoundry, prod, cloudfoundry, cloud]
2016-08-12T07:56:28.17+0200 [App/0]      OUT 2016-08-12 05:56:28.175  INFO 29 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.philips.janus.config.WebConfigurer   : Web application fully configured
2016-08-12T07:56:29.31+0200 [App/0]      OUT 2016-08-12 05:56:29.315  INFO 29 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.p.j.config.CloudDatabaseConfiguration  : Configuring JDBC datasource from a cloud provider
2016-08-12T07:56:29.80+0200 [App/0]      OUT 2016-08-12 05:56:29.807  WARN 29 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : maxIdle is larger than maxActive, setting maxIdle to: 4
2016-08-12T07:56:29.91+0200 [App/0]      OUT 2016-08-12 05:56:29.917 ERROR 29 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Exception starting filter springSecurityFilterChain
2016-08-12T07:56:29.91+0200 [App/0]      OUT org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor,java.util.List) throws java.lang.Exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'uaaWebSecurityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService com.philips.janus.config.UaaWebSecurityConfiguration.userDetailsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.philips.janus.repository.UserRepository com.philips.janus.security.UserDetailsService.userRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#5b9e4908' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#5b9e4908': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [com/philips/janus/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Cannot load connection class because of underlying exception: 'java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "[generated]@10.10.32.14:3306"'.
2016-08-12T07:56:29.91+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
2016-08-12T07:56:29.91+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
2016-08-12T07:56:29.91+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
2016-08-12T07:56:29.91+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
2016-08-12T07:56:29.91+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
2016-08-12T07:56:29.91+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
2016-08-12T07:56:29.91+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
2016-08-12T07:56:29.91+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
2016-08-12T07:56:29.91+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:368)
2016-08-12T07:56:29.91+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
2016-08-12T07:56:29.91+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
2016-08-12T07:56:29.91+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
2016-08-12T07:56:29.91+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
2016-08-12T07:56:29.91+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
2016-08-12T07:56:29.91+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
2016-08-12T07:56:29.91+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
2016-08-12T07:56:29.91+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
2016-08-12T07:56:29.91+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1060)
2016-08-12T07:56:29.91+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:326)
2016-08-12T07:56:29.91+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initFilterBean(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:235)
2016-08-12T07:56:29.91+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean.init(GenericFilterBean.java:199)
2016-08-12T07:56:29.91+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279)
2016-08-12T07:56:29.91+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:109)
2016-08-12T07:56:29.91+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4689)
2016-08-12T07:56:29.91+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5329)
2016-08-12T07:56:29.91+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
2016-08-12T07:56:29.91+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
2016-08-12T07:56:29.91+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
2016-08-12T07:56:29.91+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2016-08-12T07:56:29.91+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
2016-08-12T07:56:29.91+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
2016-08-12T07:56:29.91+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-08-12T07:56:29.91+0200 [App/0]      OUT Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor,java.util.List) throws java.lang.Exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'uaaWebSecurityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService com.philips.janus.config.UaaWebSecurityConfiguration.userDetailsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.philips.janus.repository.UserRepository com.philips.janus.security.UserDetailsService.userRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#5b9e4908' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#5b9e4908': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [com/philips/janus/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Cannot load connection class because of underlying exception: 'java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "[generated]@10.10.32.14:3306"'.
2016-08-12T07:56:29.91+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:661)
2016-08-12T07:56:29.91+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
2016-08-12T07:56:29.91+0200 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
2016-08-12T07:56:29.91+0200 [App/0]      OUT    ... 31 common frames omitted
2016-08-12T07:56:29.91+0200 [App/0]      OUT Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'uaaWebSecurityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService com.philips.janus.config.UaaWebSecurityConfiguration.userDetailsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.philips.janus.repository.UserRepository com.philips.janus.security.UserDetailsService.userRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#5b9e4908' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#5b9e4908': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [com/philips/janus/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Cannot load connection class because of underlying exception: 'java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "[generated]@10.10.32.14:3306"'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `No beans of type javax.sql.DataSource found. Skipping auto-reconfiguration.` message is coming from the [Java Buildpack auto-reconfiguration](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack-auto-reconfiguration) library. The JBP adds this library to the application classpath during staging whenever it detects a Spring application is being deployed. The library looks for a single bean of type `DataSource` in the Spring app context, and if found will swap it out for a `DataSource` bean configured with the connection details from a bound relational database service.

Do you expect this JHipster app to provide a `DataSource` bean in the Spring app context?

Instead of expecting the JBP auto-reconfig library to swap out an existing `DataSource` bean for one that is already in the app, a better approach is to have [Spring Cloud Connectors](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-connectors/) generate a `DataSource` bean from the db bound to the app. To do this, you just need to add the [Connectors dependencies](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-connectors/spring-cloud-connectors.html#_including_cloud_connectors) to your project and [enable service scanning](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-connectors/spring-cloud-spring-service-connector.html#_scanning_for_services) in your Spring configuration.

Comment: Sorry, should have posted part of my POM as well. I am already using the spring CloudFoundry connector and have a datasource for the cloud profile set. I have updated my original question to reflect this. Not sure about the @servicescan isn't it equal to @componentscan?

Comment: Since you have Connectors on the classpath, the message `No beans of type javax.sql.DataSource found. Skipping auto-reconfiguration.` is not an error but just an informational message that should be expected. `@ServiceScan` is different from `@ComponentScan`, and triggers some Connectors code to create beans from bound services. Since you have an explicit `@Configuration` class for the `DataSource` bean, you don't need this.

Comment: That leaves the `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "[generated]@10.10.32.14:3306"`. This appears to be happening because the `jdbcUrl` field in the credentials is malformed. I believe the username and password should be appended as query parameters like this: `jdbc:mysql://[host]:[port]/cf_364ff425_[remainder]?user=[username]\u0026password=[password]`. A `jdbcUrl` like `jdbc:mysql://[generated]:[generated]@10.10.32.14:3306/cf_42fa757f_80f1_[remainder]` is causing the JDBC driver to parse the first `[generated]` as the host and `[generated]@10.10.32.14:3306` as a numeric port.

Comment: If you are using the Pivotal CF MySQL product (which seems to be the case due to the `p-mysql` label, what version of the PCF MySQL product are you using?

Comment: We run our own, modified and hosted CF with a couple of Pivotal services. I tried switching to our own Postgres options which indeed work. Turns out the p-mysql is indeed deprecated and should no longer be used. Had to use the new service brokers. I suspect it was indeed a versioning issue. If you update your answer to keep versioning in mind I'll accept it.